# Load javascript script before </body> closing tag

Tags: joomla-3.4, javascript, jdocument

I'm using `$doc->addScript($path.'/js/script.js');` to load a Javascript file inside the head section. Is there any native way to load it in the bottom of the page, before the closing `</body>` tag? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't.

```
addScript(string $url, string $type = "text/javascript", boolean $defer = false, boolean $async = false)
```

You can use $defer and $async parameters of the addScript method to load JavaScript after the content.

Example:

```
$doc->addScript($path.'/js/script.js', 'text/javascript', true, false);
```

Use $defer = true if you want to load scripts in order, i.e. if one script is dependant on another.

```
$doc->addScript($path.'/js/script.js', 'text/javascript', false, true);
```

Use $async = true to load scripts asynchronously and when the order in which they are loaded does  not matter

Answer (score 0):

If you've just landed here via google see answer to this question here:

[How can I insert js scripts before </body>](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/22167/how-can-i-insert-js-scripts-before-body/22168)

Answer (score 0):

Look for a plugin called "ScriptsDown" in the JED